# How long is too long being out of InfoSec

Tags: career

This is a question related to the information security field but it is not technical in nature, more opinion based. I would really like some constructive but honest feedback.

I just recently left my job in Infosec as a member of a CERT team for 6 years, in order to move country so I can be with my wife who is going to have our first baby. I am planning to stay at home for the next 7-8 months (longest i will have been out of work) to help my wife raise the baby during the start as I know it can be hard.

The issue is that some people I talk to are of the opinion that 8 months being out from InfoSec is too long and it will be a manor obstacle to finding a new join the industry. I do hold some major certs like CISSP and CEH. I would love the opinion of some of you who are in the industry on this.

Thanks fort your time

Comment: If new people are able to enter the field it should not be a problem to catch up quickly for someone with experience. Apart  from that the question is primarily opinion based as you've noticed yourself and I propose to close it for exactly this reason.

Comment: 7-8 months does not seem so long to me (when overviewing your post I caught the "6 years" thing first, it would be another story ;) ). Just be sure to not stay completely inactive and have some concrete activity to stay trained, so you have something to convince your future employer that he will not loose money the time you get back the reflexes.

Comment: Asking explicitly for opinions on Stackexchange just asks for getting your question closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: You may also find useful information on [workplace.se]. In particular, this thread's answers may be of some interest to you: [Handling a Gap in Your Résumé (Travel experience)](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3692)

Answer (score 1):

I've had spurts where I've been out of infosec for years. Was it too long? No, it was very easy to catch up. If you're competent, infosec, like many other skills, is like riding a bike.

The biggest thing you have to worry about is explaining the gap in your resume, as WhiteWinterWolf states. Employers don't want to know you were out of work because you wanted to help raise a baby. What if your wife gets pregnant again? Off you go, huh?! You said you're changing countries, though... that is a perfectly valid excuse.

But this is opinion-based...